# PHP object composition with observer?

Tags: php, object, composition, observers

Excuse me if my terminology seems incorrect... (because it probably is)

Say i am using composition and my higher-level objects are something like:

```
abstract child
{
    /* array of Activity objects */
    public $activities;

    abstract function punish() {}
}

favoriteChild extends child
{
    function punish() {
        // Have a talk
    }
}

redHeadedStepChild extends child
{
    function punish() {
        // Beat with wrench
    }
}
```

Now let's say that `$activities` is composed of more objects, -one of which being `StealingCookiesFromJar`.

How can I call the concrete child method `punish` from inside the `StealingCookiesFromJar` object? (I'm not familiar with observers... is that what I should be learning here?)

Comment: When you call child classes like that sometimes you pass in `$this` and call it `$invoker` in the method definition. That way `StealingCookiesFromTheJar` has access to the invoking class (in this case `redHeadedStepChild`). However, strictly speaking an observing class should not need this information if you're following the observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need a concrete child inside StealingCookiesFromJar object.  Create it or pass it into a method

```
 class StealingCookiesFromJar{
    function doSomething(){
      $child = new redHeadedStepChild();
      $child->punish();
     }
  }
```

or

```
 class StealingCookiesFromJar{
    function doSomething(redHeadedStepChild $child){
       $child->punish();
    }
  }
```